# Why does the following code display 'null' instead of a value in my ajax form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to display the error message in the footer section of my ajax form but i get 'null' instead of a value what is wrong ?

[image: null displaying]

here is my code so far:

**html :**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div id="error_message"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div role="modal-footer">
```

**view.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from librarysystem.models import Users
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    template = 'librarysystem/Elib.html'
    return render(request,template)

    def validateForm(request):
        tagId = request.GET.get('id',None)           
        data = {
                'isTaken' : tagId,
                'value': request.GET.get(tagId,None),
               }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**ajax code:**

```
function validateForm() {
    tagId = this.id;
    $.ajax({
         url: "/librarysystem/validate/",
         data: {
                 tagId: this.value,
                 'id': tagId,
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
            $('#error_message').html(data.value + ' = value').css('color','red');
         }
    }) ;
}

$(document).ready(function() {                                         
    $("#username, #emailid, #password, #retrypassword").keyup(validateForm);
});
```

Comment: python array's are same as javascripts ?

Comment: `data: {
                 tagId: this.value,
                 'id': tagId,
         },` isn't this confusing? although `this` is not what you think here.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is in wrong context:

```
function validateForm() {
        tagId = this.id;
    var val = this.value; // <-----get value here
    $.ajax({
         url: "/librarysystem/validate/",
         data: {
                 tagId: val, //<----pass it here
                 'id': tagId
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
            $('#error_message').html(data.value + ' = value').css('color','red');
         }
    });
}
```

or use `context:this,` option in the ajax:

```
function validateForm() {
        tagId = this.id;

    $.ajax({
         url: "/librarysystem/validate/",
         context:this, //<----add it here
         data: {
                 tagId: this.value, 
                 'id': tagId
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
            $('#error_message').html(data.value + ' = value').css('color','red');
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be logically incorrect.

```
tagId = request.GET.get('id',None)   ## Which returns username based on the request
```

Second line

```
data = {
       'isTaken' : tagId,
       'value': request.GET.get(tagId,None) ## request params doesn't have any key as "**username**" and is supposed to return null. 
}
```

Comment: request.GET.get(tagId,None) will be expanded to request.GET.get('username',None) which will get the value returned by 'this.value' in ajax ???